# Not getting the right degree of parallelism for http queries when using Parallel.foreach

Tags: c#, concurrency

I am trying to perform 2000 http queries at the same time. 
Tests conducted with this code (consisting mostly of responding servers) run in about 15 seconds :

```
    public void testTasks()
    {
        var urls = new List<string>();
        urls.AddRange(createUrls());
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        ConcurrentQueue<string> contents = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        Task.WaitAll(urls.Select(url =>
        {
            var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
            return client.GetAsync(url).ContinueWith(response =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var content = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    contents.Enqueue(content);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            });
        }).ToArray());
        var end = DateTime.Now;
        var time = end - start;
        Console.WriteLine("Time spent in Tasks : " + time.TotalSeconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Queue size : " + contents.Count);
    }
```

Now I perform the same test, with Parallel.foreach and i get a running time of 1 minute, 18 seconds :

```
    public void testParallelForeach()
    {
        var urls = new List<string>();
        urls.AddRange(createUrls());
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        ConcurrentQueue<string> contents = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        Parallel.ForEach(urls, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = urls.Count }, url =>
        {
            var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
            try
            {
                string content = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
                contents.Enqueue(content);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        });
        var end = DateTime.Now;
        var time = end - start;
        Console.WriteLine("Time spent in ParallelForeach : " + time.TotalSeconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Queue size : " + contents.Count);
    }
```

As you can see, I am using a MaxDegreeOfParallelism equal to the number of servers. But it does not seeem to be enough.

EDIT

So my questions are :

-Why do I have such a difference in performance ?

-Can we achieve the same performances using parallel.foreach ?

Comment: The second one isn't taking advantage of the asynchronous call and thus is tying up the threads while waiting for the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I am wondering is, can we get the same performances using Parallel.foreach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -Why do I have such a difference in performance ?

Because there is no point in using `Parallel.ForEach` for IO bound work. `Parallel.ForEach` is designed for CPU bound work only. Also `Parallel.ForEach` has a "ramp up" effect, it does not start at `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, it starts with 1 thread then keeps adding threads as it detects the work could use more threads until it reaches `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` (there is a reason it is called "***Max**DegreeOfParallelism*" not "*DegreeOfParallelism*"). Using IO bound work instead of CPU bound work greatly messes up that scheduling algorithm.

> -Can we achieve the same performances using parallel.foreach ?

No you can't because you are using the wrong tool for the job, the incorrect approach will always outperform a more correct approach (which your first method is)

However using a `Async` method then immediately calling `.Result` on it is still a wrong approach, the best way would use proper async/await (also use a `Stopwatch` instead of a `DateTime` to mesure elapsed time and dispose of your disposable classes you created)

```
public async Task TestTasksProperly()
{
    var urls = new List<string>();
    urls.AddRange(createUrls());

    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    ConcurrentQueue<string> contents = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(url => QueryUrl(url, contents)))).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0;
    Console.WriteLine("Time spent in Tasks : " + time);
    Console.WriteLine("Queue size : " + contents.Count);
}

private static async Task QueryUrl(string url, ConcurrentQueue<string> contents)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient {Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)})
    {
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            try
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                contents.Enqueue(content);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to provide a slightly different angle than Scott Chamberlain provided. It does not matter whether you use sync or async IO. What matters is what effective DOP (degree of parallelism) is being employed to send HTTP requests.

Different web services will prefer different DOPs and you need to empirically determine the optimal DOP.

The number of CPU cores has nothing to do with the optimal IO DOP. Just making sure this is understood.

The first solution is bad because it chooses DOP = urls.Count. The second one is bad because it chooses DOP to be whatever the TPL decides (it is *not* equal to `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = urls.Count` because that is a *maximum*). None of these values are likely to be optimal.

1. Use one of the well-known techniques to implement a parallel async foreach with exact DOP (e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx).
2. Determine the optimal DOP experimentally.

This is a very simple problem to solve. You fell into the common trap of using the TPL's built-in facilities to solve the problem. The TPL lacks the required tools to appropriately solve this.

Also note that calling `Result` negates the benefits of async IO (which are very helpful here). Use `await` instead.